# Change Manage Customer's Grid

Tags: php, magento

I have created a custom module which displays a tab and a section in admin configuration panel to manage customer attributes.

I have loaded all customer attributes with a check box each.

This is my code for displaying all customer attributes as checkboxes. I want the checkbox value selected from here to be added as a column in Manage Customer Grid.
Model/Attributes.php

```
$attributes =   Mage::getModel('customer/entity_address_attribute_collection');
    $result = array();
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
    {
        if (($label = $attribute->getFrontendLabel()))
            $result[$attribute->getId()] = $label;
    }
    $attributes1 = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_attribute_collection');
    $result1 = array();
    foreach ($attributes1 as $attribute1)
    {
        if (($label1 = $attribute1->getFrontendLabel()))
            $result1[$attribute1->getId()] = $label1;
    }
    $final = array_merge($result, $result1);

    return $final;
```

Now based on selection of these check boxes, I would like to add an extra column in 'Manage Customer' Grid.

I tried retrieving the value of selected checkbox but I just get the array index number.

```
       Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionname/groupname/fieldname');
```

Can some one tell me how to fetch the the selected checkbox value and add a column based on the selection represented by that checkbox?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Client or server side? JQuery? More info....

Comment: What do you mean by client or server side? This is in Magento back end's configuration panel.

Comment: Are you trying to do this? http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/grid-manager.html

Comment: Not exactly same. Mine is very simple which just controls the adding and removing part of columns in the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) you are destroying the correct indexes, which are supposed to be the attribute IDs. Also it's good practice to give your variables meaningful names.

```
$result = array();
$addressAttributes = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_address_attribute_collection');
foreach ($addressAttributes as $addressAttribute)
{
    if (($addrlabel = $addressAttribute->getFrontendLabel()))
        $result[$addressAttribute->getId()] = $addrlabel;
}
$customerAttributes = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_attribute_collection');
foreach ($customerAttributes as $customerAttribute)
{
    if (($custlabel = $customerAttribute->getFrontendLabel()))
        $result[$customerAttribute->getId()] = $custlabel;
}

return $result;
```

I suppose the next step is to remove the columns that your grid's parent will add, these are stored in a grid's protected `_columns` property. Not all columns are to be removed, such as the massaction column. Then add your chosen columns back in.

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    parent::_prepareColumns();
    // remove the excess columns here

    $attributeIds = Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionname/groupname/fieldname');
    $attributes = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_id', array('in' => $attributeIds));

    foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
    {
        $options = array();
        if ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'select') {
            foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions() as $value) {
                $options[$value['value']] = $value['label'];
            }
        }
        $this->addColumn($attribute->getCode(), array(
            'index'   => $attribute->getCode(),
            'header'  => $attribute->getFrontendLabel(),
            'type'    => $attribute->getFrontendInput(),
            'options' => $options
        ));
    }

    return $this;
}
```

This way may lose useful formatting like column widths, etc. so a more sophisticated way would be to work out which columns are already in place and leave them, then only remove those that haven't been selected.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. I'll keep that in mind. Also I think _prepareCollection() would have a little change too apart from _prepareColumns(). What do you think?

Comment: Also I do not wish to remove any existing columns. I just want to add an additional column if its already not present.

Comment: Trying your code did add a Column once but then started throwing Error when I tried doing it again. Also it only displays 'Array' for getSource()->getAllOptions() and doesn't actually displays the options. Like for Gender, instead of showing Male n Female,it says Array for three time in the drop down list. Can you think you can shed in some light here? Thanks

Comment: You'll need to add address attributes to the collection, it probably won't matter if you add them all without checking which are selected, and perhaps it will be a little slower. The `getAllOptions` was returning an _option array_ when the grid needs an _option hash_, because of this I've updated my answer to convert between them and also to include a sanity check that might be the cause of your error. Without knowing more about the error by looking at logs I cannot say what it really is. Maybe you can solve it yourself ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by "add address attributes to the collection"? And In any case, none of my columns are getting added? I feel _prepareCollection must also be altered.

Comment: Learn how to handle collections [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections).

Comment: Nice Tutorial! I think I did encounter it once when I first started on working on custom modules but I might take time to follow up on this tutorial and tweak it accordingly. I know you have been very helpful and generous through out. But for now do you think you can help me a little more (please) and actually point me as to how my overall Grid.php should look like so that it can add extra columns which are not present already (Pls)

Answer (score 0):

I would, in your module, set in config.xml that you are overwrting the Block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid` with your own block (which inherits from `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid`) and in your own block make a function

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('mycolumn', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('My Column'),
        'index'     => 'key',
    ));
    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

Without knowing more about your data its hard to give better advice, but this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: I believe this is my config.xml code after the modification.
'code'
    <blocks>
    <adminhtml>
    <rewrite>       
             <customer_grid>ConstantMedia_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid
    </customer_grid></rewrite></adminhtml></blocks>
'/code'

Comment: I have just edited my question for those who want a clear idea of what I need. Thanks